# Is there a way to have one text controller for multiple text fields in flutter?

Tags: flutter, textinput

I have a form where users enter a title and a description and right now I have it set up with one text controller for each textfield

```
late final TextEditingController _titleController;
late final TextEditingController _descriptionController;



@override
void initState() {
  _calendarService = CalendarCloudStorage();
  _titleController = TextEditingController();
  _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _titleController.dispose();
  _descriptionController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}


void _setupTextControllerListener() {
  _titleController.removeListener(_titleControllerListener);
  _titleController.addListener(_titleControllerListener);
  _descriptionController.removeListener(_descriptionControllerListener);
  _descriptionController.addListener(_descriptionControllerListener);
}

void _titleControllerListener() async {
  if (_event == null) {
    return;
  }
  final titleText = _titleController.text;
  await _calendarService.updateEvent(
    documentId: _event!.documentId,
    title: titleText,   
  );
}

void _descriptionControllerListener() async {
  if (_event == null) {
    return;
  }
  final descriptionText = _descriptionController.text;
  await _calendarService.updateEvent(
    documentId: _event!.documentId,
    description: descriptionText,
  );
}
```

this is the code I have for setting up the text controllers and then in the scaffold I have

```
TextField(
  controller: _titleController,
  maxLines: 1,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Title here'),
),
TextField(
  controller: _descriptionController,
  maxLines: null,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'The description of your event'),
),
```

This feels inefficient is there a better way?

I tried using one per field but can I have one and treat the whole thing as one form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a `TextEditingController` more than once but you can use the `onChanged` property on the `TextField`.
Such as:

```
TextField(
  controller: _titleController,
  maxLines: 1,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Title here'),
  onChanged: (final String value) async =>
      await _calendarService.updateEvent(
      documentId: _event!.documentId,
      title: value,)
),
TextField(
  controller: _descriptionController,
  maxLines: null,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'The description of your event'),
  onChanged: (final String value) async =>
      await _calendarService.updateEvent(
      documentId: _event!.documentId,
      description: value,)
),
```